# How to Transforming origin for painteventargs in a c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, paint

I want to draw some geometric figure as in coordinate geometry. I have written following code in a `panels` `paint event`

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

//Transforming (0,0) origin at center of the panel
g.TranslateTransform(panel1.Width / 2, panel1.Height / 2);

// For Drawing Axes
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(-300, 0), new Point(300, 0));
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(0,-300), new Point(0,300));


g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(50,50,100,100));// this circle should come in I-quad
```

[image]

Here it is understood that since, my origin is transformed to the center of the panel, 
**Points below to the horizontal line is +ve and above is -ve. and similarly Points right to the vertical line is +ve and left is -ve.**

what should I do to flip horizontal line, so that above values should be +ve and below should be -ve ( As in coordinate plane)?
and my drawn circle should come in 1-quadrant instead of 4-quadrant.

Comment: You labeled the axes correctly, the negative Y-axis is at the top of the control.  All graphics software puts (0,0) at the upper-left.  Goes back decades, related to the way CRTs worked, the electron beam started at the upper-left, moving right, then down.  You just mis-labeled the quadrants :)  It is fixable with ScaleTransform, but it tends to be easier to just get used to the way it works out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to your transformations.

```
g.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);
```